# Right way to compute mean and variance

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, variance, sampling, mean

If I take as definition of $a_{lm}$ following a normal distribution with mean equal to zero and $C_\ell=\langle a_{lm}^2 \rangle=\text{Var}(a_{lm})$, and taking the following random variable $Z$ defined by this expression :

$$\begin{aligned}
Z = \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{l_{max}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}
\end{aligned}$$

Then, the goal is to compute $\langle Z\rangle$ :

If I consider the random variable $Y=\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_\ell \bigg(\dfrac{a_{\ell m}}{\sqrt{C_\ell}}\bigg)^{2}
$, this random variable $Y$ follows a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution weighted by $C_\ell$.

1. Can I write from this that mean of $Y$ is equal to :

$$\langle Y\rangle =\langle\bigg(\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}\bigg)\rangle = (2\ell+1)\,C_\ell$$

??

and so, we would have :

$$\langle Z\rangle = \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}}\,C_\ell\,(2\ell+1)$$

??  **I have serious doubts** since the $a_{lm}$ doesn't follow a reduced Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Shouldn't it be rather :

$$\begin{align}
Z&\equiv \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell a_{\ell,m}^2 \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell C_\ell \cdot \bigg( \frac{a_{\ell,m}}{\sqrt{C_\ell}} \bigg)^2 \\[6pt]
&\sim \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell C_\ell \cdot \text{ChiSq}(1) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell \text{ChiSq}(1) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell \cdot \text{ChiSq}(2 \ell + 1). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

2. Now, I want to calculate the mean $\langle Z\rangle$ of $Z$ :

Do you agree that my case here is the computation of a mean for a weighted sum of $\chi^2$ ?

**So the computation is not trivial, isn't it ? Maybe I could compute the mean by starting from analytical :**

$$\langle Z\rangle=\sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell (2\ell + 1)\quad(1)$$

**and directly doing the numerical computation :**

$$\langle Z\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{N} C_{\ell_{i}} (2\ell_{i} + 1)\quad(2)$$

3. What do you think about this direct computation, is it correct ?

I make confusions between $(1)$ and $(2)$ above since there is each $C_\ell$ corresponds to each $\ell$ (I mean on a numerically point of view, each $C_{\ell_{i}}$ value is associated to a $\ell_{i}$ value)

4. **If the direct computation $\langle Z\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{N} C_{\ell_{i}} (2\ell_{i} + 1)$ not correct**, then I have to consider random variable $Z$ following a weighted sum of different chisquared distrbutions :

I have tried with following `R script` where `nRed` is one of the 5 bins considered and `nRow` the number of values for $\ell$ (from $\ell_{min}$ to $\ell_{max}$), and also the `Cl_sp[,i]` the vector of `nRow` values of $C_\ell$ for each bin $i$ taken into acccount.

```
   # Number of bin
   nRed <- 5
    
   # Number of rows
   nRow <- 36
    
   # Size of sample
   nSample_var <- 1000
    
   # NRow values of multipoles l
   L <- 2*(array_2D[,1])+1
    
   # Weighted sum of Chi squared distribution
   y3_1<-array(0,dim=c(nSample_var,nRed))
      for (i in 1:nRed) {
        for (j in 1:nRow) { 
          y3_1[,i] <- y3_1[,i] + Cl_sp[j,i] * rchisq(nSample_var,df=L[j])
        }
      } 
    
   # Print the mean of Z for each bib
   for (i in 1:nRed) {
     print(paste0('red=',i,'mean_exp = ', mean(y3[,i])))
   }
```

5. Is it the right thing to implement to compute the mean of $Z$ if I can't compute it analytically (see expression $(2)$ above).

I would like to compute also the variance of $Z$, maybe a simple adding in my `R script` like :

```
# Print the variance of Z for each bin
for (i in 1:nRed) {
  print(paste0('red=',i,'mean_exp = ', var(y3[,i])))
}
```

should be enough. What do you think about this ?

**UPDATE :** I am a little lost by the definitions used. For example,

does this following equalities make sense ? :

$$\begin{aligned}
Z & \equiv \sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell, m}^{2} \\
&=\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \cdot\left(\frac{a_{\ell, m}}{\sqrt{C_{\ell}}}\right)^{2} \\
& \sim \sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \cdot \mathrm{Chi} \mathrm{Sq}(1) \\
&=\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} C_{\ell} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \mathrm{ChiSq}(1) \\
&=\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} C_{\ell} \cdot \mathrm{ChiSq}(2 \ell+1)
\end{aligned}$$

That is to say, when we write :

$$\sim \sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \cdot \mathrm{Chi} \mathrm{Sq}(1)$$

Has it signification to sum distribution $\mathrm{ChiSq}$ ?

Have we got warranty to this sum will respect $\int \text{pdf}(x)\text{d}x =1$ ?

1.We have to be prudent with the notation "$\sim$" (equality about a distribution sense) and especially when we sum the name of the distribution : do you agree with me ?

2. I think that we can say that : $Y=\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_\ell \bigg(\dfrac{a_{\ell m}}{\sqrt{C_\ell}}\bigg)^{2}$ follows a weighted sum of $\chi^2$ distribution.

But i think we cannot affirm that :

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}  & \stackrel{d}{=} \sum_{\ell=1}^{N} C_\ell \chi^{2}\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{N}2\ell+1)\right)
\end{aligned}$$

because of the presence of the weighted $C_\ell$ which is different for each multipole $\ell$.

do you also agree ?

Comment: You say "we can't simply write $\langle Z\rangle=\sum\limits_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell (2\ell + 1)$". Why not?  Does your simulation suggest this is wrong?

Comment: I can't write this since there is a dependence between $C_{\ell}$ and $\ell$ (I have a $C_{\ell_{i}}$ value for each $\ell_i$ in my code). So the quantity follows a weighted sum of chisquare distribution : $\sim = \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell \cdot \text{ChiSq}(2 \ell + 1)$ : do you agree I can't write simply $\langle Z\rangle=\sum\limits_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell (2\ell + 1)$ since this dependence ?

Comment: If $\text{Var}(a_{lm})$ varies with $l$ but not $m$ then I do not understand your issue

Comment: Before talking about numerical, I think we have to see a mathematical approach : do you agree that $Z$ follows a distribution : $Z \sim \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} C_\ell \cdot \text{ChiSq}(2 \ell + 1)$. So given the fact that $C_\ell$ depends on $\ell$, I think that we have here a weighted sum of $\chi^2$ distrubution, don't we ?

Comment: This is (at least) the *third* time you have posted this version of your (very long set of) questions--and here we go again repeating the same dialog in the comments.  That's making unfair demands on the goodwill of this community.  Before posting anything more, please thoroughly study our [help] to learn how this site works.

Comment: @whuber . I must mention that, among the answers and comments that I have received, there are different interpretations about considering or not the dependence of $C_\ell$ and $\ell$ : from one side, I have 60 values of couples $(\ell_i, C_{\ell_{i}}$. From another side, I have the expression of distribution : $\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} C_{\ell} \cdot \mathrm{ChiSq}(2 \ell+1)$ which is clearly a weighted sum of $\mathrm{ChiSq}$ distribution : it is not evident for me from a numerical point of view if I have to consider or not $C_\ell$ as independent of $\ell$.

Comment: @whuber . This is just this keypoint I want to clarify : the transition between the mathematical point of view and the numerical computation of the mean and variance of the quantity $\begin{aligned}
Z = \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{l_{max}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}
\end{aligned}$ . Moreover, I have to compute after the variance of the ratio between 2 different $Z_1/Z_2$ random variables but this is another story...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can I write from this that mean of $Y$ is equal to :
>
> $$\langle Y\rangle =\langle\bigg(\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}\bigg)\rangle = (2\ell+1)\,C_\ell$$

This is correct.

You have a sum of scaled chi squared variables. You just have to adjust the means accordingly as you did correctly.

> 2. Now, I want to calculate the mean $\langle Z\rangle$ of $Z$ :
>
> Do you agree that my case here is the computation of a mean for a weighted sum of $\chi^2$ ?

Yes. The $Z$ is a sum of $a_{lm}^2$ each of which is a scaled chi squared variable.

> $$\langle Z\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{N} C_{\ell_{i}} (2\ell_{i} + 1)\quad(2)$$
>
> 3. What do you think about this direct computation, is it correct ?

This is correct. The mean of a sum of variables is the sum of the means of those variables.

> 4. **If the direct computation $\langle Z\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{N} C_{\ell_{i}} (2\ell_{i} + 1)$ not correct**, then I have to consider random variable $Z$ following a weighted sum of different chisquared distrbutions :

Not applicable

> 5. Is it the right thing to implement to compute the mean of $Z$ if I can't compute it analytically (see expression $(2)$ above).

It is not necessary here because you can compute it analytical. But yes, using simulations is a good alternative. (Another would be the use of approximations) Simulations are also good to verify whether your analytically derived expressions are correct (check whether you didn't make a sloppy mistake).